# Compare 2 datatables

Tags: c#, datatable

I have this datatables:

```
TableObrazkyD:(column name:NAZEV_OBRAZKU)
   filename1.jpg
   filename2.jpg
   filename3.jpg
   filename4.jpg
   filename1.jpg

TableObrazkyFTP:(column name:nazevF)
   filename1.jpg
   filename3.jpg
```

I want this result:

```
TableObrazkyRozdil:
   filename2.jpg
   filename4.jpg
```

I need to compare this 2 datatables and rows, which miss in TableObrazkyFTP write into datatable: TableObrazkyRozdil
Now i try this, but it write all rows, not only miss rows:

```
var neniNaFTP = TableObrazkyD.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => r.Field<string>("NAZEV_OBRAZKU"))
    .Except(TableObrazkyFTP.AsEnumerable()
           .Select(r => r.Field<string>("nazevF")));
TableObrazkyRozdil = TableObrazkyD.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(ra => !TableObrazkyFTP.AsEnumerable()
                 .Any(rb => rb[0] == ra[0]))
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

Have you any ideas please?

Comment: You want to check if the tables contain the same data in the same places or? I couldn't understand what you mean under "comper" and what you want to achieve by that.

Comment: @D. Petrov  : I need copy all rows in table: TableObrazkyD, which isnt in table:TableObrazkyFTP to new datatable: TableObrazkyRozdil

Comment: @Lukas, you have a repeated value `filename1.jpg`. Should either instance be included in the result table? If so, which one?

Comment: @Charles : I edited first post..

Comment: @Lukas, then see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following approach that uses a `HashSet<string>.Contains` for fast lookup:

```
var ftpNazevF = TableObrazkyFTP.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("nazevF"));
var ftpRows = new HashSet<string>(ftpNazevF);

var neniNaFtpRows = TableObrazkyD.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => !ftpRows.Contains(row.Field<string>("NAZEV_OBRAZKU")));
DataTable neniNaFtpTable = null;
if(neniNaFTPRows.Any())
    neniNaFtpTable = neniNaFtpRows.CopyToDataTable();
```

Note that `CopyToDataTable` throws an exception if there is no row since it creates the columns of the `DataTable` from the first row in the sequence. So you have to check that as shown above.

Comment: Just a heads up, his variable names are in Cezch, so he might not understand what you're doing very well. neniNaFTP literally translates to not in FTP

Comment: @Charles: done. But i prefer to make it understandable for everyone not only Czech speaking ;)

Comment: Completely agree, maybe add English comments if you this it's too opaque?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean you want this:

```
var TableObrazkyRozdil = TableObrazkyD.AsEnumerable()
                                      .Where(tbl1 => ! TableObrazkyFTP.Any(tbl2 => tbl1.NAZEV_OBRAZKU == tbl2.nazevF))
                                      .CopyToDataTable();
```

All of table `TableObrazkyD` that's not contained within table `TableObrazkyFTP`.

This will return:

```
neniNaFTP:(column name:NAZEV_OBRAZKU)
  filename2.jpg
  filename4.jpg
```

Comment: Yes, but how i coul write instead of tbl1.NAZEV_OBRAZKU : tbl1. column[0]?

Comment: Try `tbl1.Columns[0]`

Comment: I'm not to familiar with the DataTable class unfortunately. You might need to defer to the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var filesToExclude = TableObrazkyFTP.AsEnumerable()
                             .Select(r => r.Field<string>("nazevF")).ToArray();

var TableObrazkyRozdil = TableObrazkyD.AsEnumerable()
 .Except(r => filesToExclude.Contains(r.Field<string>("NAZEV_OBRAZKU"))).CopyToDataTable();
```